# How to get ItemArray from StringArray?

Tags: java, android

I'm using this method for converting an String array to Item array (for saving it in sharedprefrences).

```
      strings = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (Object object : itemArrey) {
      strings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
      }
      b1s.edit().putString("array", ObjectSerializer.serialize(strings)).commit();
```

But for loading it in **listview** I need to convert it again to item array (I can't use String array for **listview** for some reasons).
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Add the lines which are making problem with problem description. Your question need more code and error description.

Answer (score 1):

As Far as I Understand You need to keep "Readable Strings" for Objects and convert it back to a Object. In that case I would recommend serializing Object ArrayList to JSON directly because it has Readability(If necessary) and easy to manipulate(Encode and Decode). You can use [Json-Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)  or [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to serialize but if the object is complicated its better to use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) .

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution to this.

Basically, you want to do the reverse of what `Object.toString()` does ... for each object.  There is no general way to do that.

If you knew what the `toString()` methods of items were generating, and the strings they were generating contained *all* of the information content of the original item objects, then it would be possible (in theory) to write a custom method to parse the strings.  But you'd need to code the parse methods yourself.

The real solution is probably to serialize your `ArrayList<Item>` directly.  If necessary, solve the problem that is preventing *that* from working.

---

You ask:

> can I save serialized item array to sharedprefrences

Since you are using the `ObjectSerializer` class from `org.apache.pig`, you will be using regular Java object serialization.

That means that you can serialize an `ArrayList<Item>` if only if the `Item` class can be serialized.

And that, in turn, requires the following:

- `Item` must implement `Serializable` (directly or indirectly) AND:

  - all non-volatile instance fields of `Item` must be serializable, OR
  - `Item` must override `writeObject` and `readObject`, OR
  - `Item` must also implement `Externalizable`.

For a field to be serializable, it must be a primitive type, a serializable object type, or an array of a serializable type.  A lot of Java library types implement `Serializable`; e.g. the primitive wrappers, `String`, the `Collection` types, and so on.

Comment: in that way, can I save serialized item array to sharedprefrences?

Comment: Before I can answer that you will need to tell me where `ObjectSerializer` comes from; i.e. what is its fully qualified name.

Comment: I got that from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences